# Better approach to get result of answers

Tags: php

I have multiple questions answerable with **Yes** or **No** like this:

> 1. Question 1:  Yes No
> 2. Question 2:  Yes No
> 3. Question 3:  Yes No
> 4. Question 4:  Yes No
> 5. Question 5:  Yes No
> 6. Question 6:  Yes No

I need to get the results of combination of "Yes" answers, what I did was the traditional if else like this;

```
if($_POST[q1] && $_POST[q2] && $_POST[q5]){
    echo 'something';
}elseif($_POST[q3] && $_POST[q5]){
    echo 'something again';
}elseif($_POST[q3] && $_POST[q5]){
    echo 'something again again';
}
and so on...
```

Although it is correct, it still produces hundreds of lines of code because there's so many questions and possible combinations.

Is there a better approach? Ty guys..

**EDIT:**

Ah sorry the second is copy>paste haha, anyway... there's 37 questions, and there's many combinations like
if 1 and 2 are yes then do this... but if 2 and 3 and 4 are yes do this... I don't need every combination.

I read somewhere that you can use the 2,4,8,16,32,64,128 etc... (I don't know what they are called haha) to add to get the result. Like if 1 & 2 are yes then the result would be 6 because 2 + 4 = 6, or if 4 & 6 are yes then the result would be 80 because 16 + 64 = 80... so I can do this

```
Question 1 = <input type=text value=2 name=que[] />
Question 2 = <input type=text value=4 name=que[] />
Question 3 = <input type=text value=8 name=que[] />
Question 4 = <input type=text value=16 name=que[] />
Question 5 = <input type=text value=32 name=que[] />
Question 6 = <input type=text value=64 name=que[] />

$array = (
  6=>"1&2 are yes",
  10=>"1&3 are yes",
  80=>"4&6 are yes"
);

echo $array[array_sum($_POST[que])];
```

Is this a good approach? or is there any better?

Comment: Is there a reason that the two elseif lines are the same?

Comment: It's unclear what you really want. Do you want every combination, or just a few? What is it you're trying to do with the if statements? Either way, whenever you have more than a few `if` statements, you should consider using loops ([`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) or [`while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loops) or [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) statements, depending on the context.

Comment: Nope I don't need every combination, just some but are not repeated... see my EDIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This is pretty tricky!

I have some experience in this and after 3 goes.  Come up with a solution.  What I think you are trying to build is a "recommendation engine".  You ask several questions and provide an answer, most likely a recommendation.

You may have 37 questions, but I suspect you or your client has about 20 answers, and I bet they are keen on changing them! Or being able to see what the answers are.

What I did to solve this was to create a "logic file" where each line was evaluated to match which answer was yes or no.

So lets say you have 37 questions
if a Question1 is YES then lets use Q1 = true in the code below.

So lets build a list. Our code will go through each line to try and find a match from top to bottom. Once it finds a match it stops looking for more matches.

1. The trick is to put the most complex matches at the top.
2. Put the most simple matches at the bottom.
3. Make sure you have "catchall matches" so there is no way you could get to the end of the file without matching something.
4. Each line of code points to your answer.  The answer could be some index to a webpage, text, solution, but lets just call it A1

```html
So put the most tricky match at the top.
A10 | Q1 & Q2 & (Q3 OR Q4) # this means Q1=yes, Q2=yes, Q3=yes or Q4=yes
A9  | Q1 & Q2 & *Q3  # Use * to mean not Q3, eg Q3 must be false 
A8  | Q1 
A7  | Q2 
A6  | *Q1
```

If I answered Q1=YES and all other questions NO.
then A8 would be a match.
If Q1 = YES, Q2 = YES all other no, then A9 would be a match

You have to code up the logic engine but you are starting to get the idea.
The logic engine would have to parse you custom logic file and make logic work but that isnt toooo hard. Its fun.

Having started with OR'ing bits, like the 2,4,8,16 thing you were eluding to is FAR to hard to debug. We did that at the start of ours. It sucks...

We then wrote 100's of "if" statements, but now you have to sit down with the client beside you and try and come up with the logic. Doesnt work and it takes a VERY long time to debug.

This Logic file is great.
You can easily see that there a billions of combinations but with this file based system you can see how you arrive at each solution, which combinations must be meet.  And if they are not met, then which rule should be evaluated next.

Quick test here. with 37 yes no questions there are 2^(n-1) solutions = 68,719,476,736

So the logic file is a quick way to break down certain known combinations you want to catch and see that they are being caught (eg a line is present in this logic file).

Here is my logic engine in Python.

```
class LogicEngine(object):
    
    def filterTags(self, rules, tags):
        if(rules.strip()==""): return True # no tags means true.
        # Bracket Logic, eg...   *a & (b OR c)
        openBracket = 0
        closeBracket = 0
        while(openBracket != -1):       
            openBracket = rules.find("(",openBracket)
            closeBracket = rules.find(")",openBracket+1)
            if(openBracket!=-1):
                # found a rule, convert *a & (b OR c) to *a & TRUE, which can be then handled by logic system.
                subRule = rules[openBracket+1:closeBracket]
                if self.filterTags(subRule,tags):
                    rules = rules.replace("(" + subRule + ")", "TRUE")
                    #print rules
                else: 
                    rules = rules.replace("(" + subRule + ")", "FALSE")
                    #print rules
        
        #print rules #quick check.
        ruleList = rules.split("OR")
        
        for rule in ruleList:
            rule = rule.replace(" ","")
            rule = rule.split("&")
            if self.checkRule(rule, tags) : return True
        
        return False #no matches found means this is not valid.
    
    def checkRule(self, rules, tags):
        for rule in rules:
            if rule[0:1]=="*":
                # a NOT rule.
                rule = rule[1:] #remove star
                if rule =="TRUE": 
                    return False
                if rule =="FALSE":
                    # do nothing, keep looping.
                    pass
                elif (listContains(tags,rule)):
                    return False
            else:
                if rule =="FALSE": 
                    return False
                if rule =="TRUE":
                    # do nothign
                    pass
                elif (not listContains(tags,rule)):
                    return False
        return True
        
def listContains(list, key):
    try:
        list.index(key)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

So in short, you are really going to need to do some work here to make this go. It's not really that simple.

There very worst case is you turn the $_POST into something a bit more readable.

Then run a big list of if statements with the most complex at the top.

eg

// Answer1.html for people with hairy hands.
if($Q1 && $Q2 && !$Q3 || ($Q6 && $Q7) return "answer1.html";

// Answer2.html for people with beards
if($Q1 && $Q2 && $Q3)  return "answer2.html";

// Answer3.html for people with nose hair
if($Q1) return "answer3.html";

// Answer4.html for people with toe hair
if(!$Q1) return "answer4.html";

I would still make these statments more expressive.
instead of $Q1, make it $nosehair so you can read your conditions and answers.

Right good luck.

Comment: Let me know how you go, I spent sometime writing this wondering if you will use it, so if you do use, let me know would love to see if you solved it and if I was right?  Well the right solution for your problem.